# Haskell, error unwrapping Maybe Int

Tags: haskell

I wrote code:

```
is3 :: Int -> Maybe Int 
is3 x = is3temp 0 x 

is3temp :: Int -> Int -> Maybe Int 
is3temp p x = if (abs p*p*p) < (abs x) then (is3temp (p+(signum x)) x) else (if p*p*p == x then (Just p) else Nothing) 

c :: Maybe Int -> Int 
c (Just x) = 2*x+1 
c Nothing = 0

--fun::Int ->  Int
--fun = c.is3

c1:: Int -> Int
c1 x = 2*x +1
c1 0 = 0

fun::Int ->  Int
fun x = (is3 x) >>= c1
```

As you can see `is3` takes Int and returns Maybe Int.

In `fun` I take result from `is3` unwrap it and try to send it to c1.

And get error

```
ERROR file:1627.hs:47 - Type error in application
*** Expression     : is3 x >>= c1
*** Term           : c1
*** Type           : Int -> Int
*** Does not match : a -> b c
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: `c1` should be `Int -> Maybe Int`.

Comment: or you are looking for `fmap c1 (is3 x)` instead of `is3x >>= c1`

Comment: @bereal But why ? `fun` returns `Int`, so if `c1` will return `Maybe Int` won't it make other problem there?

Comment: @AleksanderMonk yes, `fun` has to be `Maybe Int` in order to work in the monad, as in Chris' answer.

Comment: You might like [`exactCubeRoot`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.4.1.3/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Powers-Cubes.html#v:exactCubeRoot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's inspect all types that come together in `is3 x >>= c1`:

```
x            :: Int
is3          :: Int -> Maybe Int 
c1           ::                      Int ->   Int
                                     |||     /???\
is3 x        ::        Maybe Int     |||    ???????
(>>=)        ::        Maybe a   -> (a   -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b
(>>=) is3 x  ::                     (Int -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b
is3 x >>= c1 ::                                         $!%&/#?
```

As you can see, `c1` doesn't work as right hand side of `>>=`, since it's return type is wrong. It must return some kind of `Maybe`. One can easily fix this with `return . c1`:

```
return . c1  :: Int -> Maybe Int
```

or with `fmap`, since the monad laws dictate that both must have the same effect:

```
fmap c1         :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
fmap c1 (is3 x) ::              Maybe Int
```

However, this will also change `fun`'s type. That being said, your functions name are rather bad and `c1` is probably a typo (if `fun`'s type is correct). It's possible that you actually wanted to use `c`:

```
fun :: Int -> Int
fun x = c (is3 x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some code that compiles:

```
is3 :: Int -> Maybe Int
is3 x = is3temp 0 x

is3temp :: Int -> Int -> Maybe Int
is3temp p x = if (abs p*p*p) < (abs x) then (is3temp (p+(signum x)) x) else (if p*p*p == x then (Just p) else Nothing)

c1 :: Int -> Int
c1 0 = 0
c1 x = 2*x +1

fun :: Int -> Maybe Int
fun = (fmap c1) . is3
```

I changed the type of `fun` from `Int -> Int` to `Int -> Maybe Int`, and am using `fmap` instead of `>>=`.

Also I flipped the order of the matches in `c1`. Matches are applied top to bottom, so the `0` case never would have applied in the order you have it.